# Jquery masonry center layout with images didn't apply on load

Tags: jquery, layout

I am working on a hobby project which uses Jquery masonry to lay out the items in my page. I use center layout so that no matter how many items I have, they always end up in the center of my page. In fact, it works. The problem is that when the page first loads, the layout is not centered, but on the left of the page. Then it 'jumps' to the desired layout.

Here is my an [URL](http://learnviashow.org/shows/) to show you what I mean by that. Notice that the layout isn't 'correct' after the sudden jump. What I want is eliminate the jump, make the layout centered right when the layout is presented to users.

I used ImageLoaded plugin with masonry. Here is the related code:

```
$('#elements').imagesLoaded(function(){
            $('#elements').masonry({
                itemSelector: '.element',
                columnWidth: 245,
                gutterWidth: 6,
                isFitWidth: true,
                isAnimated: true
            });
});
```

And to center the layout I add following rules to #elements:

```
#elements{
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

As indicated by the masonry document [here](http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/centered.html).

So what's my problem then? Thanks for any input.

**EDIT**:

Thanks to @Bendim, I figured the way to do this. I have written my answer below but there is still one remaining problem: it takes a while for the whole interface to present itself, which is not ideal. Anyway, I will work on this. Thanks again, @Bendim.

Comment: Have you tried specifying a `width` for your `mainContent` container.

Comment: @KristerAndersson I did that before I want it to be as fluid as possible. So When I resize the page I want the items to animate the columns change but still stay centered on pag. If I specify the width, then I can't do that.

Comment: You could set the width in percent.

Comment: @KristerAndersson let my have a try~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Bendim gave me an idea I meant to try for a while. But when I hide the #elements div, my element overlapped after I make it fade in. So instead I hide .element div, then fade in them. Here is what I did:

```
.element {
    display: none;
}
```

then right after the masonry code:

```
$('#elements).mansory(
    ...
);

$('.element').each(function(i){
    $(this).fadeIn('fast');
});
```

It worked perfectly, no jumps at all.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. My solution is to hide the `div` with the masonry elements and fade it in after everything is leaded. The fallback for user without javascript was important for me.

```
<head>
<title>Example</title>
<style type="text/css">
#elements {
    /* hide the elements to avoid jumping */
    display: none;
}
</style>
<!-- fallback for people without javascript -->
<noscript>
<style type="text/css">
#elements {
    /* overriding the css above */
    display: block !important;
}
</style>
</noscript>
</head>
<body>

Your page content…

<!-- load all jquery from google, with fallback to local file -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

<!-- load jQuery plugin that triggers a callback after all images have been loaded -->
<script src="/jquery.imagesloaded.min.js"></script>

<!-- load masonry script -->
<script src="/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var options = {
        itemSelector: '.element',
        columnWidth: 245,
        gutterWidth: 6,
        isFitWidth: true,
        isAnimated: true
    };
    var $container = $('#elements');
    $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
        /* div with content fade in */
        $('#elements').fadeIn(1000);
        /* if all images are loaded it runs the masonry script */
        $container.masonry(options);
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! But my elements overlap when I hide #elements. Instead I hide each element then make them appear.

Answer (score 0):

If you will render images with fixed height and width, they will not overlap. My solution is to use php function `getimagesize($pathToImage)`, if you have fixed width (for example 260px), you just need to use this method

```
<?php 
$imageInfo = getimagesize($pathToImage);
$originalHeight = $imageInfo[1];
$originalWidth = $imageInfo[0];
$height = (260/$originalWidth) * $originalHeight;
print "<img src='path/to/image.jpg' widht='260px' height='$height'>";
?>
```

Images printed with this method will not overlap. Images which will be loaded later with js not needed to set height at all, so you only need to set fixed height to that images, which will be rendered by php, not js.